# Route to a different page in a different flow from webhooks in Dialogflow CX

Tags: routes, webhooks, dialogflow-cx

I would like to redirect to a page in another flow from a webhook. For instance, when a page calls a webhook, the webhook can redirect to a page in a different flow.

```
res["target_page"] = "projects/[id project]/locations/[id location]/agents/329b4fd2-6273-41b3-a113-ab2d53ae923b/flows/ead52edd-e7c2-46c8-af31-6c7b1e7c6678/pages/c563fc10-7058-4ae8-842e-d439560bdbe5"
```

when the webhook is triggered, I got this strange error:

[image]

It appears that when I select a Page, it defaults to the main flow even though I've specified the flow ID as 'ead52edd-e7c2-46c8-af31-6c7b1e7c6678'. I've tried entering different values, but it still considers the default flow '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'.

Is this a bug, and how can I correctly specify the flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [webhookResponse](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.cx.v3#webhookresponse), you can set the fulfillment_response and target_page fields to send a fulfillment response as well as transition to another page respectively. Here’s an example below:

```
{
    targetPage: projects/<Project ID>/locations/<Location ID>/agents/<Agent ID>/flows/<Flow ID>/pages/<Page ID>,
    fulfillmentResponse: { 
        messages: [{ 
            text: [“Text response from webhook”],
        }] 
    } 
}
```

Here’s a sample result:

[image]

IMPORTANT: If it is in a different flow, you will have to specify the property `targetFlow`, you can use either `targetFlow` or  `targetPage` but not both at the same time: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rest/v3/TransitionRoute

When you transition to flow, it starts from the start page!

Comment: so, if I want to specify a different flow, I have to add targetFlow like this?
targetPage: projects/<Project ID>/locations/<Location ID>/agents/<Agent ID>/flows/<Flow ID>/pages/<Page ID>/TargetFlow

?

Comment: now should be

{
    targetFlow: projects/<Project ID>/locations/<Location ID>/agents/<Agent ID>/flows/<Flow ID>,
    fulfillmentResponse: { 
        messages: [{ 
            text: [“Text response from webhook”],
        }] 
    } 
}